# jquery call to buttonset holding up everything else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several divs (about 100 or so) of class 'checkboxViewset' on my page. I attempt a buttonset call on the divs using the classname selector as below :

```
$('.checkboxViewset').buttonset();
```

This ends up holding up the entire page. So I attempted to do this by using a selector by targeting the ids instead with the each loop as below:

```
$('[id^=viewBoxlatest_]').each(
     function (index)
     {
        $(this).buttonset();
     }
);
```

This still ends up holding everything else up on the page. Is there any solution to make these calls asynchronous instead of holding up all other activities in the page?

Comment: Can we have a view of what buttonset() does?

Comment: @Angel : buttonset() is part of the Jquery UI framework. Please refer to http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of not giving you much hope ....

It could be said that any javascript statement "holds up" every other statement that comes (chronologically) after it in the same event thread, and potentially (because javascript is single-threaded) future threads in their entirety.

With that in mind, I think the point here is not so much that `.buttonset()` holds everything else up but that it is slow (when applied to 100 containers) and that its inherent slowness is insurmountable unless you are able to find/write an alternative plugin that runs faster.

Your most realistic hope of better apparent performance is to change the order of execution such that your `$('.checkboxViewset').buttonset();` statement executes after the code that it currently holds up.

Try the following :

- Move the statement to the bottom of the event handler in which it sits.
- Place the statement in its own late-firing $(function(){...}) handler.
- With the rest of your jQuery in $(function(){...}) handler(s), place the statement in its own `window.onload = function(){...}` handler. The penalty here is that users will most likely get a Flash of Unstyled Content (FOUC) before `buttonset()` styling is applied.

Edit:

On another train of thought entirely, you could try serving a single div's worth of buttons, styling it with `.buttonset()` then cloning it 99 times to make the 100. The viability of this approach would of course depend on your divs being structurally identical and not requiring their own unique ids/values/data.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Truly appreciate it. I'm going to attempt to do a late firing of the buttonset calls. I think FOUC is far more acceptable than the user waiting ( for what seems to be an indefinite wait).